# add client certificate http request

Tags: blackberry, java-me, x509certificate

How can i attach a client certificate in a http request in java-me? 
In c# i would simply do this as

```
 request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate());
```

where request is an instance of  **HttpWebRequest**.